# On the differentiability of a certain map from $ (0,\infty) $ to $ \Bbb{R} $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

This problem arose from my study of energy-conservation for non-linear Schrödinger equations. Suppose that we have the following data:

- $ u \in C^{1} \! \left( (0,\infty),{L^{2}}(\Bbb{R}^{n}) \right) $.
- $ g \in {C^{b}}(\Bbb{R}^{n}) $.
- $ G: [0,\infty) \to \Bbb{R} $ is defined by $ \displaystyle G(s) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \int_{0}^{s} g(\sigma) ~ \mathrm{d}{\sigma} $.
- $ F: \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{R} $ is defined by $ F(z) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \dfrac{G \! \left( |z|^{2} \right)}{2} $.

Then the following question may be asked:

> **Question:** Is it true that the derivative of the map
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{matrix}
> (0,\infty) & \to     & \Bbb{R} \\
> t          & \mapsto & \displaystyle
>                        \int_{\Bbb{R}^{n}} F(u(\bullet,t)) ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu}
> \end{matrix}
> \right\}
> $$
>   exists and is equal to
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{matrix}
> (0,\infty) & \to     & \Bbb{R} \\
> t          & \mapsto & \operatorname{Re} \!
>                        \left( \left\langle
>                        \dot{u}(\bullet,t),u(\bullet,t) ~
>                        g \! \left( |u(\bullet,t)|^{2} \right)
>                        \right\rangle_{{L^{2}}(\Bbb{R}^{n})} \right)
> \end{matrix}
> \right\}?
> $$
>   **Note:** Here, $ \dot{u} $ denotes the time-derivative of $ u: (0,\infty) \to {L^{2}}(\Bbb{R}^{n}) $.

This is formally true, but when one tries to formulate a rigorous proof, obstacles arise. One obstacle is the fact that the time-derivative $ \dot{u} $ of $ u $ is not taken ‘pointwise’ at points in $ \Bbb{R}^{n} $ but rather as a map from $ (0,\infty) $ to $ {L^{2}}(\Bbb{R}^{n}) $.

I could show that the map is locally Lipschitz continuous, so it is differentiable almost everywhere. However, this is far from answering the question posed.

Thank you!